# Reprojecting Geotiff using GDAL?

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff

I am new for GIS programming. I try to change geotiff coordinate system from epsg 32635 to epsg 4326. I used the following gdal command:

```
gdalwarp -rc -s_srs epsg:32635 -t_srs epsg:4326 -dstnodata 0 -of GTiff -co tiled=yes UU5L.tif UU5L_rej.tif
```

The source image is on the left and the result is on the right.

[image]

Obviously something went wrong. When I check metadata on result image, I see that corner coordinates in second cell are not the same as source image second cell.

What do these corner coordinates mean? I know first values are image place on Earth, but second?

Here is a little example:

Corner Coordinates:

```
Upper Left  (  500000.000, 7530000.000) ( 27d 0' 0.00"E, 67d53' 4.61"N)
Lower Left  (  500000.000, 7434000.000) ( 27d 0' 0.00"E, 67d 1'24.61"N)
Upper Right (  596000.000, 7530000.000) ( 29d17' 2.00"E, 67d52' 7.37"N)
Lower Right (  596000.000, 7434000.000) ( 29d12'10.21"E, 67d 0'29.74"N)
Center      (  548000.000, 7482000.000) ( 28d 7'18.05"E, 67d27' 0.64"N)
```

---

Now i'll understand more, today i face a new challenge.
I have two different geotiff files both has wgs84 crs (epsg:4326).

First tiff will show rectangular area, but second tiff looks like baseball field i mean top of map has curved line and bottom has short curved line, both side lines are also curved on the center of area.

So do i have any change to handle second tiff so it would looks like first one?

I have been using gdal scripts for handling, can i do that for gdal?

Answer (score 2):

If you add both layers to QGIS and switch `On-the-fly-reprojection` on, they should align. Maps in degrees (EPSG:4326) always look squeezed the more to the poles you come. So nothing wrong here.

The first coordinate pair are metres, measured from 27°E +500km and the equator. The second ones are degrees. They are not rectangular anymore due to the reprojection.

Answer (score 0):

The UTM Stuff has not axis parallel Nort-South and East-West corners (..see [conformal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection#Conformal) versus [Transverse Mercator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transverse_Mercator_projection) projection). So the image will be turned into an axis parallel Longitude Latitude space with the blanked black gaps you see...